# Zend view in another view

Tags: zend-view

I have a problem with Zend view . I wont to call a view in another view . How can I do it .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what zend framework logic intends.

You should create a [**View Helper**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) and move the code that you want to reuse to the view helper.

Comment: I use this way $this->Action("view","controller","module", array(params)) it is working